# how do I re-duplicate sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, stress-testing, replicate

I would like to stress test my database, which is a hospital patient database.

The current one is 2 GB. I would like to have a 100GB database, so I would like do the following:

1) read each patient record
2) create a new, fake patient id, and store back to database
3) repeat until size reaches 100GB

What is the easiest way of doing this? Are there tools for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would expect that your smaller database won't be a great stress test.  It would be best if you can duplicate the environment that is in production, so copy the database and create new patient ids if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with SSIS?  If so, you can change your PK to add a 2G value to make it unique, then copy all the rows from your source table back to the same table as the destination.

Comment: Thanks, Beth. I am not familiar with SSIS, but it looks like it might be useful. Can you point me to any resources on these tools?